# Anylogic Material Handling Library runtime

Tags: java, model, runtime, simulation, anylogic

I delevoped a simulation model using both the Process Modeling Library and the Material Handling one. I would like to make a simulation that last for a month (in Anylogic time) so that i can use schedules to describe working hours, truck arrival and so on, but when i run the model i get the message "Material Library in Anylogic Personal Learning Edition allows simulation of 1 hour only. Please specify simulation stop time."
In the properties of the Simulation Experiment window in the section Model Time I already set the Stop field as "Never",but i continue to get the error.
Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: The limitation is specified in the editions comparison on the Downloads page: https://www.anylogic.com/downloads/. (See the "Industry-specific libraries" entry.)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, for the PLE version, you can simulate by using industry-specific libraries (like Material Handling) for 3600 seconds only. You simply can't run for a month with PLE. That's why it suggests you to deselect "never" and put the end time 1 hour after the start time.

Comment: Glad that my answer was useful. Please don't forget to accept as answer and upvote if you like so that others can also benefit.